# Why redefined operator delete is faster then original operator delete?

Tags: c++

There is 2 class

Class DataOri and class DataMod are almost same except operator new/delete.

I redefined operator new/delete for class DataMod.

```
class DataOri
{
    int v1[100];
    char c1;
    int v2[7];
    char c2;

    public:
         DataOri();
}

class DataMod
{
    int v1[100];
    char c1;
    int v2[7];
    char c2;

public:
    DataMod();

    static void* operator new (size_t size)
    {
        if (GetReporter())
        {
            ++(GetReporter()->AllocNodeCount());
        }
        return malloc(sizeof(DataMod));
    }

    void operator delete (void *p)
    {
        free(p);
        if (GetReporter())
        {
            --(GetReporter()->AllocNodeCount());
        }
    }
}
```

I estimate the time for new/delete 1000000 times

DataOri New Time [485838]

DataOri Del Time [821767]

DataMod New Time [499649]

DataMod Del Time [808503]

I can understand DataMod New is slower then DataOri New

because DataMod New do more thing, increasing count

but I can't understand DataMod Del Time is faster then DataOri Del Time

even DataMod Del do more thing, decreasing count

Comment: How did you compile?

Comment: Please include the minimal code that lets us reproduce this behavior and the compiler version + compilation settings you used. There are many things that can go wrong when benchmarking, your question is too incomplete to tell what's going on.

Comment: what is T in sizeof(T)?

Comment: above result under debug.

Comment: i test under release mode now and i get reasonable result DataMod's new/delete slower then DataOri's

Comment: @BaummitAugen i added more code

Comment: @bashrc it's my mistake, i fixed it. thx

Comment: @user2523112 *"above result under debug"* Then this is the culprit. The performance of unoptimized C++ code is meaningless, this it pretty much by design of the language. Try a release build.